# php7 + nginx + vds + debian + ssmtp: "самопроизвольная" отправка писем сервером

Tags: php, nginx, debian, smtp

Настраиваю возможность отправки сообщение на почту через mail(), php7, nginx, vds, debian

Попробовал Sendmail, не получилось, поставил ssmtp.
Так мне теперь постоянно приходит на почту выполнение моих крон задач. Каждую секунду приходят письма.

Вот так выглядят заголовки писем:

`Cron <www-data@debian9x64> sleep 60; /usr/bin/php /var/www/домен/web/engine/modules/bots/groups/179460906.php`

У меня вообще не стоит функция отправки писем, он сам как-то генерирует и спамит мне на почту.

Comment: Предоставьте, пожалуйста, как можно больше информации: исходники, конфиги, логи. В общем, всё, что может помочь другим дать Вам корректный ответ.

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста какие именно файлы логов необходимо скинуть?

Comment: К сожалению, я не силён в тех средствах разработки, с помощью которых Вы хотите решить свою задачу. Возможно, другие члены сообщества смогут более подробно объяснить, что необходимо предоставить. Я просто даже на первый взгляд вижу, что информации явно недостаточно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего вам падают письма от `root`. Поправим расписание:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Чтобы запретить отправку по крону, нужно в расписании указать пустой адрес почты:

```
MAILTO=""
```

Получится что-то вроде этого:

```
MAILTO=""

# Задачи
*/2 * * * * задача-по-расписанию > /dev/null 2>&1
```

В этом примере также используется `> /dev/null 2>&1`, такая конструкция перенаправляет оба вывода (ошибки и стандартный вывод) в никуда, в этом случае письма также не будут отправляться (по сути-это второй способ выключить отправку письма о выполнении задачи).

Если письма приходят от кого-либо еще, используйте это:

```
sudo crontab -e -u{имя-пользователя-в-системе}
```

Comment: Не знаю почему так происходит. Но удалив sendmail и убрать из php.ini это строку sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/ssmtp -t, спам перестал лететь и письма отправляются как я и хотел.

Comment: @ДмитрийМовсесян, крон выполняет задачу, и отправляет письма. Это нормальное поведение. И файл `php.ini` тут не причем. Решение я написал в ответе

Comment: Сделал как вы написали. Вроде перестали лететь. СПАСИБО Вам ОГРОМНОЕ!